# Checking svn return

Tags: python, svn

I would like to know if a svn branch already exist or not using a script (python by instance).

Svn info doesn't seem to return any error by definition. What would be the best way to check if the branch does exist then ? 
I am currently using `os.system('svn info token')`
I get : token:  (Not a versioned resource) as output. How can I manipulate the return code in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Two options:

1) Shell out an svn command.  It seems like the `svn ls` command will return 0 on success and 1 on failure.

```
foo@bar:~/$ svn ls https://svn.domain.com/svn/projectX/branches/realbranch
/bin/
foo@bar:~/$ echo $?
0
foo@bat:~/$ svn ls https://svn.domain.com/svn/projectX/branches/notabranch
svn: warning: W160013: URL 'https://svn.domain.com/svn/projectX/branches/notabranch' non-existent in revision 22746
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
foo@bar:~/$ echo $?
1
```

2) Research and leverage the python bindings